Swiper - keeps flickering on local dev and not in CodeSandbox
my Swiper worked properly and did stop at the last slide in CodeSandbox but keeps flickering in my local dev project.
CodeSandbox's dependencies:
swiper 11.1.8
vue ^3.4.15
Local dev's dependencies (package-lock.json):
swiper 11.0.5
vue 3.4.21
My project's homepage-feed.vue:
<template>
    <swiper
        :modules="modules"
        :slides-per-view="1"
        :autoplay="{
          delay: 1000,
          stopOnLastSlide: true,
        }"
        @swiper="onSwiper"
        @slideChange="onSlideChange"
    >
       <swiper-slide>1</swiper-slide>
       <swiper-slide>2</swiper-slide>
       <swiper-slide>3</swiper-slide>
   </swiper>
</template>

<script>

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/vue";
import { Autoplay } from "swiper/modules";
import "swiper/css";

export default {
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide,
  },
  setup() {
    const onSwiper = (swiper) => {
      console.log("swiper");
    };

    const onSlideChange = () => {
      console.log("slide change");
    };

    return {
      onSwiper,
      onSlideChange,
      modules: [Autoplay],
    };

</script>

I had a look at the console:
Can see the "slide change" message.
Under <target>: Object { __swiper__: true:
activeIndex: 2
autoplay: Object { running: true, paused: true, timeLeft: -14683123, … }
isEnd: true

Spent a good couple hours at the official documentations and still did not have a clue.
Is there something to do with the CSS or? Any pointers will be much appreciated!
